# Loading a set of recursively typed elements in F#

Tags: recursion, f#

Suppose we had a table of vendors in a SQL database that we want to load into F#:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID |  Name  | Parent |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | Nest   | 2      |
|  2 | Google | NULL   |
|  3 | Apple  | NULL   |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Using type providers it is easy enough to get the table into F#, but suppose we wanted to then convert the data into a sequence of Vendors, where Vendor is a type like this:

```
Vendor = {ID: int; Name: String; Parent: Vendor option}
```

How would one go about doing that? The issue is that when creating the sequence of Vendors we can't map to each row a particular Vendor, since we don't have the sequence of Vendors yet. It would be good to also assume that the application allows for cycles (A could have B as a parent and B could have A as a parent), although in the case of vendors that doesn't really make sense.

You could instead define the Vendor type as:

```
Vendor = {ID: int; Name: String; ParentID: int option}
```

But this seems much less elegant, since every time you would want to reference the parent vendor you'd have to do some sort of lookup. Is there a known solution to this? It seems like a situation that could occur often (especially when dealing with graphs or trees).

It also seems like a solution could involve some sort of lazy evaluation, but it's not clear to me how the Lazy<'T> type in F# could be applied here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a particularly elegant solution, but the one that uses lazy evaluation for the parent would look something like this: you would have two types, one that matches the schema of your table and one recursive:

```
type Flat = { ID: int; Name: string; ParentID : int option}

type Recursive = { ID: int; Name: string; Parent: Lazy<Recursive> option}
```

Then let's set up something that looks like your table:

```
let records = 
    [
        { ID = 1; Name = "Nest"; ParentID = Some 2 }
        { ID = 2; Name = "Google"; ParentID = None }
        { ID = 3; Name = "Apple"; ParentID = None }
        { ID = 4; Name = "Yin"; ParentID = Some 5 }
        { ID = 5; Name = "Yang"; ParentID = Some 4 }
    ]
    |> List.map (fun x -> x.ID, x)
    |> Map.ofList

let getRecord recID = records |> Map.find recID
```

And you can put it together like this:

```
let rec getRecordRecursive recID = 
    let record = getRecord recID
    {
        ID = record.ID
        Name = record.Name
        Parent = 
            record.ParentID 
            |> Option.map (fun pid -> 
                Lazy.Create <| fun () ->
                    getRecordRecursive pid)        
    }
```

So in a sense you're using the lazy type to delay the next step of recursion until you need it. Otherwise `getRecordRecursive 4` would give you a stack overflow.

But there are tradeoffs - you no longer get nice behaved equality on such records, for instance. I'm not convinced you're not better off with `Flat` records in the long run.

Comment: Drats, I was hoping for a more elegant solution to exist. Thanks!